# Unable to map list in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to modify all the data in a `mutableListOf` but I am not succeding.

For what I've read it is possible: `The mapping operation returns a modified list by applying a transform function on each element of the list.`

My code is something like this:

```
val secValue = 110.0
val alertValue = 180.00

val maxValue = 0.111111
val mediumValue = 0.0909090909
val topValue = 0.7353
var data = mutableListOf<Double>(11.0, 28.0, 30.0, 24.0, 34.0, 31.0, 32.0)
 data.map {it ->
      if (it <= secValue)   {it*mediumValue}
      else if (it <= alertValue) {it * maxValue}
      else {it * topValue}
  }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to capture the result of `data.map{}`. I don't think it modifies the list.

Comment: I've thought the same. Do you know how?

Comment: Just assign it to a new variable, or the same one. `data = data.map{}`.

Comment: I've already tried, but it is not possible

Comment: Why is it not possible? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I had an empty list to which I was assigning the result but I was not working. I'll edit the question with the solution. Somehow, you've helped me ;)

Comment: No, don't edit the question with the solution, post it as an answer.

Comment: "The mapping operation **returns a modified list**" - this is pretty clear

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes, but it does not say anywhere that the output list would be a List, not a list of the same type as the input list, in this case a mutableList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
 var result = data.map {...}
```

The problem was that the map function was returning a `List<T>` not a `MutableList<T>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using API >= 24 you can use Java 8's [`List.replaceAll(UnaryOperator<E> operator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-)

```
data.replaceAll {it ->
        if (it <= secValue)   {it*mediumValue}
        else if (it <= alertValue) {it * maxValue}
        else {it * topValue}
    }
```